# can't install perforce extension for php (system:windows sp3)

Tags: php, pecl

```
pecl and pear is installed.
```

I type these in cmd.exe

```
pecl install perforce-1.0.3.tgz
```

then comes the feedback:

```
6 source files,building
php_bin D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php5.3.5\php.exe,but config variable php_suffix does not match
ERROR:The DSP perforce.dsp does not exist.
```

Comment: You may have luck with this:  http://serverfault.com/questions/309119/error-when-install-apc

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing but... should you unzip that perforce.tgz *before* you try to install it?

(I don't know how pecl works... perhaps it automagically unzips as it goes...)